# How to get the modified array of object if arraylist have value in object property based on condition using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For the given arrayobject and arraylist, if the arrList details exists in listArrObj, then return the country as shown in the output

Tried

```js
var listArrObj =[
  {id:1, country: "IN", details: ["all", "some"]},
  {id:2, country: "SG", details: ["all", "some"]},
  {id:3, country: "AU", details: ["some",]}
]
var arrList = ["all", "few", "some"]

var result = arrList.map((key) => [
  key,
  listArrObj.filter((x) => x.details && x.details.includes(key)).map((x) => x.country),
]);

console.log(result);
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
   detail: "all",
   country: ["IN", "SG"]
  },
  {
   detail: "few",
   country: []
  },
  {
   detail: "some",
   country: ["IN", "AU", "SG"]
  }
]
```

Comment: If you expect an array of objects, why does your outer map return an array?

Comment: Can you explain why `SG` isn't in the country list for your last object in your expected output? `listArrObj` has `"some"` as a value in its `details` array for `SG`

Comment: @NickParsons thanks, yes  updated the output, SG should be present

Comment: You just need to change your first `.map()` to return an object instead of an array as jonrsharpe mentioned. `.map((key) => ({detail: key, country: listArrObj.filter....}))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the result. You are returning an `array` instead return an `object` which contains `detail` and `country` property

```js
var listArrObj = [
    {
        id: 1,
        country: "IN",
        details: ["all", "some"]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        country: "SG",
        details: ["all", "some"]
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        country: "AU",
        details: ["some", ]
    }
]
var arrList = ["all", "few", "some"]

const result = arrList.map(str => {
    return {    
        detail: str,
        country: listArrObj.filter(obj => obj.details.includes(str)).map(o => o.country)
    }
})

console.log(result);
```